# Get request data before returning from function in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, axios

I have a NextJS app (using `axios` for requests) which interacts with a backend API and this requires an auth token. I have written a function to get the auth token beforehand and store it in a module-level variable in my frontend api file.

This, however, causes the token to be fetched multiple times since when the token is fetched it takes a while, thus allowing other token fetch calls (for other API requests that need to take place) to be called since the module-level token variable is still empty (because the other API request(s) which are fetching the token are still doing it)

How would I write this token-retrieval function so that it makes only the first call fetch, making subsequent calls wait for a value to be set by the first call if this has not ben done already?

Here is the relevant code:

```
let authToken: string = ''

async function getToken () {
    if (!authToken) { // only run if we don't already have the token
        const url = generateUrl(`/api/auth/token`);
        const r = await axios.get(url);
        if (r.status == 400) {
            // (the user is not signed in)
        }
        authToken = r.data.token;
    }
    return authToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should lazy-create a Promise for a token only once. Promises are created instantly, but can take some time to settle.

Using this approach any number of requesters can wait on the eventual settlement of the same Promise. In this implementation you would probably never directly call getToken()...

```
let tokenPromise: null | Promise<string> = null;

export async function lazyGetToken() : Promise<string>{
  if(!tokenPromise){
    tokenPromise = getToken()
  }
  return await tokenPromise;
}

async function getToken () : Promise<string>{
    const url = generateUrl(`/api/auth/token`);
    const r = await axios.get(url);
    if (r.status == 400) {
        // (the user is not signed in)
    }
    return r.data.token;
}
```